# Using a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for my AWS Server

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, tomcat

I have a website at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) that's using a Let's Encrypt wildcard certificate. It works great.

I also have a webapp that's running under Tomcat on an AWS EC2 instance. It runs at webapps.example.com so it could hypothetically use the same SSL cert.

I can download the SSL certs, but is it possible to install them in my EC2 instance? There's no Load Balancer, just a single instance so I don't think I can use Cert Manager or anything like that. How should I go about doing this? Do I configure this at the Tomcat level? The nginx level? Any ideas?

Comment: More info needed. Is the website and the webapp hosted on the same server / instance? Do they have the same URL with different paths? Or different URLs?

Comment: If you can get the private key and certificate file then it will likely work.

Comment: The website is hosted on a commercial hosting site. The webapp is hosted on AWS. Completely different servers but they share a common base domain so the wildcard cert that I have is appropriate for both.

Comment: I can get the cert and private key. But what do I do with them?